# Is there a way to add instructions directly on a entry index screen in the CP?

Tags: plugins, control-panel

I have structure entries that needs to be in a very specific order, following a pattern of horizontal and vertical images to create the right affect on the front-end. I would love a way that I could remind my client of the instructions for the right order of these entries directly on the entries index screen in the CP, sort of like how you can provide instructions for each field. Are there any plugins that would allow the injection of some instructions into the CP page like this?

I've seen option to that allow you to create entire users manuals or help sections in the CP, but that's not what I'm after. I want something that could go inline on just a single CP page.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin, it allows you to add text (instructions) as a field:

https://github.com/thomasthesecond/EntryInstructions